# Singleton with time-based lifespan

Tags: c#, singleton

I'm trying to implement a singleton-like class, that would have a lifetime based on time. Instances created in every 5-second period from the start of the program should be the same, as in a normal singleton, and between the different 5-second spans there should be different singleton instances. What I came up with is a list that would store the singleton instances, instead of the typical static instance field. However I'm still getting the same instance when I test it. Here's the code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TimedSingleton t1 = TimedSingleton.Instance();
            Thread.Sleep(5500);
            TimedSingleton t2 = TimedSingleton.Instance();

        Console.WriteLine(t1 == t2);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class TimedSingleton
{
    private static ArrayList _instancesArrayList = new ArrayList();
    private static List<int> AddedPositions = new List<int>();

    private static DateTime _startTime = DateTime.Now;

    protected TimedSingleton()
    {
    }

    public static TimedSingleton Instance()
    {
        int index = (int) DateTime.Now.Subtract(_startTime).TotalSeconds%5;

        if (AddedPositions.Count == 0)
        {
            _instancesArrayList.Add(new TimedSingleton());
            AddedPositions.Add(index);
            return (TimedSingleton)_instancesArrayList[index];
        }

        if (AddedPositions.Contains(index))
        {
            return (TimedSingleton) _instancesArrayList[index];
        }

        AddedPositions.Add(index);
        _instancesArrayList.Add(new TimedSingleton());
        return (TimedSingleton) _instancesArrayList[index];
    }
}
```

Result: `true`

How can I fix it to return separate instances for each 5-second timespan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the fiddling with the indexes in a list and arraylist I changed your implementation  to use a generic [`Dictionary<tkey, tvalue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) instead so the index can be a simple lookup. Keep in mind that this keeps adding items so if called often enough you'll run out of memory. There is no clean up here.

```
class TimedSingleton
{
    // have a dictonary to hold the seconds
    // and the instance so we can lookup
    private static Dictionary<int, TimedSingleton> AddedPositions = new Dictionary<int, TimedSingleton>();

    private static DateTime _startTime = DateTime.Now;

    protected TimedSingleton()
    {
    }

    public static TimedSingleton Instance()
    {
        // divide by 5
        int index = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(_startTime).TotalSeconds / 5;
        Debug.WriteLine(index);

        // 
        TimedSingleton result;
        // if you're going to multhreed this
        lock(AddedPositions)
        {
            // try to get the index seconds ...
            if (!AddedPositions.TryGetValue(index,out result))
            {
                // not happened
                Debug.WriteLine("Created new instance");
                result = new TimedSingleton();
                // store it for later
                AddedPositions.Add(index, result);
            }
            else
            {
                // result has now a previous instance
                Debug.WriteLine("from cache");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you very much. I actually did eventually end up using Dictionary myself, but the modulo instead of the division by 5 kept ruining it for me and I couldn't find out why, thanks for pointing that out.